# Using MATLAB, why does something like fts.data work in one directory but not another?

Tags: matlab

I am working with the financial tooldbox that has a type called FINTS. If I copy some code out of its toolbox directory to customize it, when I try do do something like fts.data, `I get

> The specified field, 'data', does not exist in the object.

But the same thing works fine in the MATLAB library directory. They are both in my path, so what else do I need to change?

Comment: I found some more info: The directory the original file exist in is a @fints directory which means it has something to do with the class fints.  How can I define a local file having to do with this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. MATLAB defines class methods in what it calls method directories which are named after the class. So in this case, the class is `fints`, so all its methods are in `@fints`. All I had to do was make a new directory in my own workspace called `@fints`, and it will become another class method of `fints`. You can see all the methods a class has by calling `what className`.

Comment: I would be wary about making multiple @-folders if you are using a newer version of MATLAB. Here is a quote from the end of [this online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynrp-1.html#brfynrp-4): "In MATLAB Versions 5 through 7, @-folders do not shadow other @-folders having the same name, but residing in later path folders. Instead, the class is defined by the combination of methods from all @-folders having the same name. **This is no longer true.** " The example given at that link illustrates this.

Answer (score 2):

I think, but I haven't checked the documentation on this one, that it is a peculiarity of [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) that the class `FINTS` must be defined in the directory `@fints`. So if you want to extend the class, you have to put your code into that directory. And if you want to work on a class `MYFINTS`, you need to put the code into directory `@myfints`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is specified from the root directory, and not relative.

For instance

```
addpath 'c:\...\...\MATLAB\mytoolbox
```

not

```
addpath 'mytoolbox'
```

the latter will break if you change your working directory

Comment: All my paths are not relative, but I don't think this problem is a path thing, since I can run scripts fine out of either directory.  But  it doesn't seem to know what a FINTS is outside of the @fints/ directory.